# MySQL: выборка уникальных записей и их количество в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с объявлениями, мне нужно вытащить оттуда список городов без повторения, но и к каждому городу показать сколько объявлений для него содержится. Вывести список городов получилось, а вот как посчитать количество объявлений для каждого города и при этом не делать тысячу лишних запросов, не вышло.

Список городов получаю так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM advert WHERE COMPLETE=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CITY, COUNT(*) FROM advert WHERE COMPLETE=1 GROUP BY CITY
```

Answer (score 1):

`select city,count(distinct post) from advert where complete=1 group by city`

`post` - объявления. Вполне возможно `distinct` не нужен.

Answer (score -2):

в средине `while(...fetch_array())` для  каждого `$row[city]` делайте запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ...
```

ИМНО. Это множество запросов будет быстрее выполнятся, чем  большой JOIN/IN запрос

Comment: если же нужно количество уже выбранных. просто используйте $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Количество городов более 2х тысяч, тоесть в цикле сделать еще 2 тысячи запросов?

Comment: неужели  уникальных городов будет более 2000?

Comment: Да, и количество явно растет